# Playwright-Python Script on Ubuntu 22.04 with Flask + Gunicorn. Playwright Error Exception('Connection closed while reading from the driver')

Tags: ubuntu, flask, gunicorn, playwright-python

I have a Flask App that has a route that triggers a Playwright script install on ubuntu 22.04 with ngnix. However, the playwright script does not seem to trigger as it keep getting the error. Playwright Error Exception('Connection closed while reading from the driver')

I have tried reinstalling but it still does not respond. I have tried to run it via a subprocess call it also does not run and gets the same error.

I do wish to know if it is the ports configuration that is causing this issue or Playwright not able to find its path. Given that the playwright scripts works perfectly fine via python3 playwrightscript.py. Just not working when trying to invoke the script via flask API.

I do wish to know if anyone know an alternative method that I can use or a solution to this issue given that I have tried to find solutions on the net and cant seem to find any that would resolve this issue.

```
#the playwright script is sync and call start in this method where the script gives the error.
playwright = sync_playwright().start()
```

Any help would be appreciated.